# Como hacer la última parte del ejercicio

Tags: javascript

/* DESDE LOS NUMEROS 50 AL 150, HAZ QUE LOS NUMEROS DIVISIBLES ENTRE 3 Y 5 SEAN SUSTITUIDOS POR HOLA Y ADIOS Y LOS QUE SEAN DIVISIBLES ENTRE 3 Y 5 POR IRONHACK. INTENTA HACERLO CON SOLO UN CONSOLE.LOG */

```
for (var i = 50; i <= 150; i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {        
            console.log('Ironhack');
        } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
            console.log('hola');
        } else if (i % 5 ==0) {
            console.log('adios');
        } else {
            console.log(i);
        }
}
```

No se me ocurre como hacerlo solo con 1 solo console.log, tened en cuenta que la solucion no debe ser muy abstracta ya que son ejercicios basicos que deberia poder sacar con comandos de nivel principiante.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facil, simplemente utiliza una variable asi:

```js
for (var i = 50; i <= 150; i++) {
        var valor="";
        if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {        
            valor = 'Ironhack';
        } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
           valor = 'hola';
        } else if (i % 5 ==0) {
            valor = 'adios';
        } else {
            valor = i;
        }
        console.log(valor);
}
```